# Do I need to use localhost or dns name to start php chat server?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have a chat, but I want to run this chat in AWS EC2, in my script I have this line of code

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
```

But I don't want to host it in localhost of my ec2 instance, I want to run to all people, so I need to host in my dns, right?
Then, I need to remove *ws://localhost:3000* and add the dns of my website? I really don't know if I need to do that

Comment: If you host it in a server, you will be provided a public IP address of the server. You will need to use that instead of `localhost`. Also, you need to use a DNS, if you want a domain / subdomain name in place of localhost. Look for Route53, if you want to manage DNS in AWS or use your DNS provided by Domain service provider.

Comment: Understand, I did it, but no success. Can you help me with any software like team viewer? Please, I don't know what to do anymore, that's so confuse

Comment: Is the chat server running on your server? And did you configure your firewall?

Comment: Also, did you apply for the port 3000 in security groups?

Comment: I did it, thank you very much, you really helped me, after you told me that I analyzed it well and started looking at the browser console to see what was going on, now the connection is starting, thank you very much, thank you